# How to solve placeholder CSS difference across different browsers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, placeholder

I am using Twitter bootstrap CSS. Below you can see how the same code is displayed differently with FireFox and Chrome.

This is quite strange. Firebug tells me that the placeholder's css is set like this to light grey:

```css
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
}
```

This should affect all placeholders within all elements as its correctly done in Chrome. 
But in Firefox why are `textareas` correctly applied, but `input` is not?  How can I fix this?

```
<input id="id_referred_by" type="text" maxlength="50" name="referred_by" placeholder="...was referred by?">

<textarea id="id_contacts_interests" name="contacts_interests" cols="40" placeholder="Any particular interests?" rows="4"></textarea>
```

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

**update:**

The comments below gave me an idea:

`Input` has unlike `textarea` the `color: #9999` entry crossed out, which means something is overriding it.

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

It is in fact this `color: #555555;`. When I disable it in firebug, it all works.  How comes Chrome doesn't care about this but Firefox do? Any tips how fix this across both browsers? I am still new to css.

Comment: it works for me here - http://jsfiddle.net/WHTmC/ but you might want to try to define the rule like this `input:-moz-placeholder`

Comment: so strange. I can see your code works online.  But locally it doesn't. Can can this possibly be so? Same local code is different on two browsers...

Comment: you might have a CSS rule with higher priority on that input field, like `#formName input { color: #000 }`

Comment: Makes sense, but shouldn't it affect Chrome as well? :)

Comment: maybe it's a rule with `-moz-` :)

Comment: ahhh you might be right. `Input` has unlike `textarea` the `color: #9999` entry crossed out.  I found what is causing it. See updated question please. Still strange.

Comment: works locally with `input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}` . this line of course can be put in an overriding css file. tested in firefox 14.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made a little fiddle a while ago because of this weird pseudo-element, the result ? You can't add a coma between the selector, you have to specify your rule twice, that's a shame.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test-webkit" placeholder="test-webkit" /><br />
<input type="text" id="test-moz" placeholder="test-moz" /><br />
<input type="text" id="test-both" placeholder="test-both" /><br />
<input type="text" class="test-both" placeholder="test-both-separately" />​
```

The CSS:

```
/* Works on Webkit */
#test-webkit::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Works on Firefox */    
#test-moz:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Don't work */
#test-both::-webkit-input-placeholder, #test-both:input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Works on both */
.test-both::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
.test-both:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}​
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/NvFCW/).

Comment: Interesting. I can see the difference. Thank you.  Applying this solution to all placeholders seems difficult. I have tried to paste the last two lines without the `.test-both::` but that `color: #555555;` still overrides it. I ended up overriding it on purpose to fix it across both browsers like this: `input[type="text"] { color: #999999;}`. Not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Under Firefox 19 I have to use `.test-both::-moz-placeholder` instead of `.test-both:-moz-placeholder`(note the two colons instead of a single one).

Comment: You have to specify the issue several times because the browser interpretes the rule as one. The properties like -webkit can not be found in Firefox. Thus the whole line is rendered as an error.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that Firefox change the opacity of the field, and with that you think its a different color, but its not... add "opacity:1;" and it will work exactly the same in all browsers

```
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
    opacity: 1;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: took me about 1m before I picked up the difference, very subtle.

Answer (score 2):

As an update below a full list of placeholders you need to use. :-moz is deprecated in newer firefox versions.

You need to specify the rules several times and can not combine them on a single line. This is due to the fact that the browser will interpret them as a single selector. It will cause an error because Firefox does not know the webkit rule.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:#bbb;
  font: 12px Verdana, Arial,Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color:#bbb;
  font: 12px Verdana, Arial,Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  color:#bbb;
  font-family: 12px Verdana, Arial,Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font: normal;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:#bbb;
  font: 12px Verdana, Arial,Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your firefox cache (it may be enough).

and inspect with firebug

install firebug if it's not allready done https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

right click on the input, and click on Inspect Element with Firebug.

to see if there's a css property with an higher priority.

[image]